# Detecting Textures in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, fft, detection, template-matching

I'm trying to detect a texture using OpenCV. The texture would be similar to that of a brush on a paintbrush, so on an image it would have many many little lines together. I've tried using Hough Lines to be able to distinguish the texture from other things, but it hasn't been working out too well, as too many other false positives are detected. Other than that, I've had ideas about using Template Matching as well as Fast-Fourier Transforms, but I haven't tried testing or implementing them.

So, would anyone else have any idea of a possible method to do this? Maybe use some other line detector or an edge detector? Or would that bring up too many false positives?

This texture should be able to be detected in a cluttered scene and the algorithm for doing so should be relatively fast, since I want it to be tracked in real-time if possible. Sorry for not being able to post a sample of the texture I want (too less rep l0l), but you can simply search up paintbrush/paintbrush texture if you really need to see what it looks like. But if you've seen a paintbrush before, it should be pretty obvious which part I'm talking about (the part with the brush).

Thanks in advance, really appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by little lines together? something like barcode?

Comment: @arkiaz Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I was just trying to describe the texture of a brush, since I'm trying to detect the brush portion of a paintbrush. If you've seen a paintbrush before the brush part looks like a lot of little lines together. 
The 'lines' on a paintbrush would be packed closer to each other compared to the lines on a barcode.

Comment: Texture analysis is still an unexplored area of computer vision.  If you figure out how to do this, please let us know.